# UPDATE row inserted earlier in CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Is it possible to update a value inserted earlier on in a CTE, or does the whole transaction have to be committed first before the value can be updated?

I have this "circular dependency" where `B` requires the id from `A`, but then if a certain condition is met in an `other_table`, then `A` should be updated with the generated `id` in `B`.

I tried the following but the field in `A` that I try to `UPDATE` does not seem to update properly (`UPDATE 0`). The rest of the query works as expected.

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    a_id serial,
    col_a text,
    column_to_update text
)
;
CREATE TABLE table_b (
    b_id serial,
    a_id int,
    other_table_id int
)
;
CREATE TABLE other_table (
    other_table_id int,
    condition_col bool
)
;
INSERT INTO other_table (other_table_id, condition_col)
VALUES (1, FALSE), (2, TRUE)
;
```

`INSERT`+`UPDATE` statement:

```
WITH insert_a_query AS (
     INSERT INTO table_a (col_a) VALUES ('hello')
     RETURNING a_id
),

insert_b_query AS (
     INSERT INTO table_b (other_table_id, a_id)
     SELECT other_table_id, (SELECT a_id FROM insert_a_query)
     FROM other_table
     RETURNING other_table_id, b_id
)

UPDATE table_a
SET column_to_update = b_id
FROM other_table
LEFT JOIN insert_b_query ON other_table.other_table_id = insert_b_query.other_table_id
WHERE other_table.condition_col = TRUE
AND table_a.a_id = (SELECT a_id FROM insert_a_query)
```

**Resolution with work around as per @laurenz-albe**

```
WITH a_sequence AS (
    SELECT nextval('table_a_a_id_seq') AS a_id
),
insert_b_query AS (
     INSERT INTO table_b (other_table_id, a_id)
     SELECT other_table_id, (SELECT a_id FROM a_sequence)
     FROM other_table
     RETURNING other_table_id, b_id
)

INSERT INTO table_a (a_id, col_a, column_to_update)
SELECT
    (SELECT a_id FROM a_sequence)
    , 'hello'
    , b_id
FROM insert_b_query
LEFT JOIN other_table ON other_table.other_table_id = insert_b_query.other_table_id
WHERE other_table.condition_col = TRUE
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work, like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#sql-with) says:

> The primary query and the WITH queries are all (notionally) executed
>   at the same time. This implies that the effects of a data-modifying
>   statement in WITH cannot be seen from other parts of the query,
>   other than by reading its RETURNING output. If two such data-modifying
>   statements attempt to modify the same row, the results are unspecified.

A workaround would be to explicitly call the `nextval` function on the associated sequences in a first CTE and perform the two `INSERT`s afterwards.